# Partition of the real line.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I want to show that there exist sets $A_x \ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t:
$A_x\cap A_y =\emptyset , \forall x\ne y$, $\cup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} A_x = \mathbb{R}$ and $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} : \ |A_x|=\aleph$.

I thought of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ such as $(0,x)$ but this doesn't cut it, since the first criterion of disjoint intervals doesn't hold.

I don't see how to define this.
Any help?

Edit: for those who don't know $\aleph$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ also known as the continuum.

Comment: When you wote $\aleph$, did you mean $\aleph_0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos no, I meant what I wrote!

Comment: Then what does $\lvert A_x\rvert=\aleph$ mean?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist What is $\aleph$?

Comment: I believe $\aleph$ means $2^{\aleph_0}$. I saw this notation before, though it is rare.

Comment: By the "continuum hypothesis, [tex]2^{ℵ_0}= R[/tex] so you want Ax= {x}.

Comment: @0XLR , aleph means the cardinality of the continuum;

Comment: @user247327 what you suggest won't work since $|A_x|=| \{ x\} | =1$ and not $\aleph$!

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Then I suggest you mention that $\aleph$ is the cardinality of the continuum in your question since I have never seen that notation before.

Comment: Blast!  I misread the problem!

Comment: @0xlr ok, I will.

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist I believe it's more normal to use $\mathfrak{c}$ for the cardinality of the continuum, by the way.

Comment: @PatrickStevens to tell you the truth, I don't understand why it's more normal? the book I use uses this notation. But I guess since Cantor wasn't really normal... :-D

Comment: Why does the English word "lame" more normally mean "unable to walk" than "a razor on a stick used for slashing dough"? It just… is more normal.

Comment: How do you define "normal"? do you call the author who wrote the book I am using not so "normal"? anyway, I appreciate it if someone can help me with my question instead of declaring what is "more normal".

Comment: To *some* extent, this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr/.

Comment: Closely related: [A partition of the unit interval into uncountably many dense uncountable subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463601/13130) *AND* [Uncountable collection](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/649294/13130) *AND* [Uncountable family of uncountable compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55880/13130) *AND* [Nice partition of $\mathbb{R}$ into uncountably many uncountable sets](https://mathoverflow.net/q/300764/15780).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:(0,1)\to\Bbb R$ be a bijection. We will do the required activity with $(0,1)$ and then use our bijection to get it done for $\Bbb R$.

Take $x\in(0,1)$. Let its infinite binary expansion be $0.x_1x_2x_3\cdots$. Let $B_x$ be the set of all $y\in(0,1)$ such that the $(2n-1)th$ term in the infinite binary expansion of $y$ is $x_n$. Then $\{B_x|x\in(0,1)\}$ is an uncountable partition of $(0,1)$.

Now, let $A_x=f(B_{f(x)})$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. We are done!

Comment: do you mean $x_n$ instead of $x_i$? since as you wrote it, I don't see the connection between the indices $i$ and $2n-1$.

Comment: Yes, I mean that. Corrected the typo.